# ora-12899 error in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have created a table

```
SQL> DESC Customers


Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ACCT_ID                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 ZIP_CODE                                           CHAR(5)
```

I tried to insert a line into the table

```
INSERT INTO customers (acct_id, name, zip_code)
VALUES ('1234567890', '(Danelle)', '(20743)');
```

I get this error and i cant seem to fix it.

> ERROR at line 2:
>   ORA-12899: value too large for column "CM420E08"."CUSTOMERS"."ZIP_CODE"
>   (actual: 7, maximum: 5)

I am only entering 5 digits but its saying i am entering 7. any ideas?

Comment: You really should practice your counting skills... Open paren + 5 numeric digits + closing paren, wrapped in quotes, is 7 characters. Try again - `(12345)`. You'll probably want to take a look at how you're handling the name as well, unless your first name really is `(Danelle)` (in which case you spelled it wrong in your profile here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are entering 7 characters-- your `name` and `zip_code` strings appear to have a "(" as the first character and a ")" as the second character.  You probably want

```
INSERT INTO customers (acct_id, name, zip_code)
VALUES ('1234567890', 'Danelle', '20743');
```

Comment: Thank you for responding it was successful. I was following step by step instructions and looks like user error.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at your `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO customers (acct_id, name, zip_code)
VALUES ('1234567890', '(Danelle)', '(20743)')
```

You are actually trying to enter the string `(20743)`, which is the five digit zip code wrapped in parenthesis.  You should either insert `20743`, or make the `ZIP_CODE` column 7 or more characters wide.

Comment: Thank you so much.I was following steps for a homework assignment. I really appreciate it